# Error in accessing root of virtual machine via PuTTy

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, putty, esxi5.5

I want to access root of my vSphere ESXi 5.5 Ubuntu virtual machine through PuTTy. So I loaded the public i.p. of the vm, and tried SSHing through port 22.

This gave the following error:

[image: PuTTy fatal-network error]

I went into the sshd config file and changed the port from 22 to 443 and tried to ssh again through port 443, but getting a terminal session where I couldn't type anything.

I changed the port again in the config file to port 80, and tried again through PuTTy. This time I got another PuTTy fatal error.

[image: PuTTy fatal error-server closed]

Has anyone here gotten around this problem?

Comment: Normally you would only log on as root from the console, not remotely, and it's likely that the default setting is to disallow remote connections from user root. When connecting remotely, you should log in as a normal user and use sudo to perform any actions as root.

Comment: Ubuntu has no root user *password* by default.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek It does have a root user, it's just disabled by not having any valid password. Every Linux system has a root user, as discussed e.g. in [Does the root account always have UID/GID 0?](https://superuser.com/a/626845/53590). There may or may not be a mapping to a *username*, but the user exists either way.

Comment: I'm thinking that something is responding to port 80, but it isn't properly communicating with the SSH protocol.  If you tell PuTTY that you want to connect with the Telnet protocol, instead of SSH, you'll likely get different and more usable results.  (Even then, your results probably won't be very useful if you're not familiar with the commands of the HTTP protocol.)

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't really say anything, I'm going to assume that you have a relatively stock Ubuntu installation in that VM.

It muddies the water slightly when you say that you are using the "public" IP address of the VM, because this could mean a few different things.

However, one thing is worth noting: Your original error ("Network error: Connection refused" when you try connecting to port 22) tells you that **you were able to reach the system running inside the VM, and that system said that nothing is listening on the particular IP address and port combination that you reached it on.**

I'm pretty sure that the workstation Ubuntu installations do not ship a running SSH server by default. The server variants, however, might very well do so.

Use the VM console to log in, and check whether a SSH server is running. I don't have an Ubuntu system handy at the moment, but in a terminal, this should be similar to

```
$ service sshd status
```

It might be referred to as something like `ssh`, `ssh-server`, `openssh-server` or something along those lines instead of `sshd`, but tab completion on `ssh` (type `ssh`<kbd>tab</kbd>) should get you close. You *may* need to `sudo` this, so e.g. `sudo service sshd status`, but I think regular user access should be sufficient to get a service status (running/stopped) report.

If no SSH server is running, or even installed, then that explains why you got a "Connection refused" error. Install a SSH server using something like:

```
$ sudo apt-get -u install openssh-server
```

Verify that the list of packages to be installed looks sane, and confirm. The SSH server will be started at the end of the installation process.

Now, look at /etc/ssh/sshd_config. It will have zero or more `Port` and `ListenAddress` directives giving IP addresses or port numbers (the port number defaults to 22 if not specified, and the server will listen on all IP addresses if you don't explicitly tell it otherwise). **That's the IP address and port you need to connect to.**

If no IP address(es) are specified, `ip addr show` will show you the network interfaces within the VM and their respective IP addresses. Those are the ones the SSH server will be listening on.

Armed with this information, perform whatever magic incantations are required to get PuTTY to connect to this combination of IP address and port. (This may involve punching a hole or configuring port forwarding in a NAT or firewall, for example.)

Once that is done, **you should be able to connect using PuTTY and get a terminal session as an unprivileged user on the Ubuntu VM.** From there, use `sudo` to elevate your privileges on an as-needed basis, just as if you were sitting in front of a physical system.

I recommend setting up public key authentication, and I very much recommend **against** allowing root to log in directly. However, if you absolutely *must* allow root to log in directly, then edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config and specify `PermitRootLogin yes`, then `sudo passwd root` and give root a *good* password, and restart the SSH daemon. Again, **I do not recommend this.**

With that out of the way, **what was the issue with your connecting to ports 80 and 443?** Port 80 is the default port for HTTP, and port 443 is the default port for HTTPS. If a web server is running, it is likely that it is listening on both of those ports, and **when you connect, it will be expecting HTTP requests; in the case of port 443, after SSL negotiation.** It is certainly possible to manually issue HTTP requests, but it isn't a terminal login session and a shell. In general, connecting to random ports (even well-known ports) is unlikely to get you the result you are after.

Comment: I'd add, some newer versions run systemd rather than upstart, so commands may be a little different.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Actually, I think `service sshd status` is how you'd do it with systemd. It certainly is in Debian Jessie, which decidedly does *not* use Upstart.

Comment: service is depreciated somewhat in distros that do systemd - its systemctl. You'd get a warning message for many commands using `service`

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Good point. OP hasn't specified which Ubuntu release though, so the specifics would be a bit of guesswork either way.

Answer (score -1):

inside Ubuntu machine, open /etc/ssh/sshd_config and change PermitRootLogin to yes.

```
# Authentication: 
LoginGraceTime 120 
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes
```

Comment: You'd also have to set up some method of authentication, given that Ubuntu doesn't give `root` a valid password in a default installation. So either set up public key authentication, or log in to an account with sudo privileges and do `sudo passwd root` to give root a **good** password.

Comment: Its also a *terrible* idea to allow remote root logins - especially without other security methods like key based auth.

Comment: I assume he has already set the root password.